# cut important parts of string in a column

Tags: string, pandas, slice

i have a column called `Dateiname` which contains a string. my goal is to get only the string `Gruen` `Gelb` `Orange` from the column and create a new column which represents each row if it contains `Gruen` `Gelb` `Orange`

i tried with this code:

```
result['Y'] =  result.Dateiname.str[-10:-4]
```

as these words are not equally long i get 4_ or 1_ or just _, depending if it is Gruen or Gelb which i want to slice out. Is there any possibility to get the parts `Gruen` `Gelb` `Orange` of the column Dateiname and save it into the column `Y`?

[image: <code>Gruen</code> <code>Gelb</code> <code>Orange</code>]

the goal would be this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
result['Y'] =  result.Dateiname.str[-10:-4].str.extract('(Gruen|Gelb|Orange)')
```

Another solution is [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) by `_` or `.` and get second value from end by indexing:

```
result.Dateiname.str.split('_|\.').str[-2]
```

Or if want check all data:

```
result['Y'] =  result.Dateiname.str.extract('(Gruen|Gelb|Orange)')
```

Answer (score 1):

If your data follows same format as `required_word` followed by `.csv` then use [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with regex:

For Example:

```
result = pd.DataFrame({'Dateiname':['asdfjaskld_3242_34.fsdf_450_Violet.csv',
                                'asdfjaskld_3242_34.fsdf_450_Green.csv',
                                'asdfjaskld_3242_34.fsdf_450_Indigo.csv',
                                'asdfjaskld_3242_34.fsdf_450_Red.csv']})

result['Y'] = result.Dateiname.str.extract(r'([a-zA-Z]+).csv')

print(result)
                                Dateiname       Y
0  asdfjaskld_3242_34.fsdf_450_Violet.csv  Violet
1   asdfjaskld_3242_34.fsdf_450_Green.csv   Green
2  asdfjaskld_3242_34.fsdf_450_Indigo.csv  Indigo
3     asdfjaskld_3242_34.fsdf_450_Red.csv     Red
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
result['Y'] = result['Dateiname'].str.split('_').str[-1].str[:-4]
```